# Arduino can't find substring in string in received serial text from device

Tags: android, arduino, substring

I am setting up a send GPS position from an Android to and Arduino so that the Arduino will follow the Android phone. I get a string from the Android and I seem to get it correctly and get the proper length but I can't find the identifier ("Lon" or "Lat") from the string.

I get the a string from the Android, I put the array of received bytes into an array, I converted the array to a string and I tested it to check if it is a string and I checked the length of the string and it all appears to be legit but I can't identify if my identifier is in the string to extract the data.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
// Example 2 - Receive with an end-marker

const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];   // an array to store the received data
String mlong;
String mlat;
long mlong_val;
long mlat_val;
String temp_mlat_val;
String temp_mlong_val;
String temp_str;
boolean newData = false;

SoftwareSerial BT_Serial(10, 11);

void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial.println("Bluetooth receive 003");
      BT_Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    recvWithEndMarker();
    showNewData();
}

void recvWithEndMarker() {
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char endMarker = '\n';
    char rc;

    while (BT_Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = BT_Serial.read();

        if (rc != endMarker) {
            receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
            ndx++;
            if (ndx >= numChars) {
                ndx = numChars - 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
            ndx = 0;
            newData = true;
        }
    }
}

void showNewData() {
    if (newData == true) {
        Serial.print("This just in ... ");
        Serial.println(receivedChars);
        String temp_str = receivedChars;      
        Serial.print("This is the string, I hope ");
        Serial.println(temp_str);
        unsigned int lastStringLength = temp_str.length();
        Serial.print("This is the length of the string, I hope ");
        Serial.println(lastStringLength);
        if (temp_str.substring(lastStringLength) == "Lat"){
          Serial.println("Lat");
          }
        else {Serial.println("After looking for Lat, not found");
        }  
        newData = false;
    }
}
```

---

```
void loop() {
  // Set up a String:
  String stringOne = "Content-Type: text/html";
  Serial.println(stringOne);

  // substring(index) looks for the substring from the index position to the end:
  if (stringOne.substring(19) == "html") {
    Serial.println("It's an html file");
  }
  // you can also look for a substring in the middle of a string:
  if (stringOne.substring(14, 18) == "text") {
    Serial.println("It's a text-based file");
  }
```

---

tried this replacing their string with my string in my code

```
 if (newData == true) {
    Serial.print("This just in ... ");
    temp_str = "Lat12.34567";
    Serial.print("This is the string, I hope ");
    Serial.println(temp_str);
    unsigned int lastStringLength = temp_str.length();
    Serial.print("This is the length of the string, I hope ");
    Serial.println(lastStringLength);
    if (temp_str.substring(lastStringLength) == "Lat"){
      Serial.println("Lat");
      }
    else {Serial.println("After looking for Lat, not found");
    }  
    newData = false;
```

and it doesn't work with just the string, not from the Android

Expect to just print "Lat" if the identifier "Lat" was located in the string, it doesn't print

Comment: If you want to look for text in a string then use find, not substring.  Right now substring is returning the entire string and that isn't equal to just Lat.  You could use startsWith, or find, but substring doesn't do what you think it does here.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't mean find, I mean indexOf.  That's the one in String that searches for a substring and tells where it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, been away for the w/e trying it now